# "The call is ambiguous" (Calling a method with the same data structure)

Tags: c#, string, methods

I'm trying to call a method (`EmptyFolderContents`) with the (`recent`) system variable, but I get this message:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

So how do I rename/change this?

```
String recent = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%") + "\\Recent";

EmptyFolderContents(recent);

private void EmptyFolderContents(string folderName)
{
    foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.Delete(folder, true);
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(excep);
        }
    }

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(excep);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that you have got 2 methods with the same signature in the same scope. So just Change the name of any one method to something EmptyFolderContents_New

Comment: Provide the full error message. It means you have another method with the same name/parameters within the same class

Comment: It sounds like Windows can't tell if you are trying to delete the shortcuts (.lnk files) in that folder or the files that the shortcuts are pointing to. I'd be careful with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you have got 2 methods with the same **signature** in the same **scope**. Either remove the unwanted method from the scope or change the name of any one method to something

```
       private void EmptyFolderContents_New(string folderName)
```

then call it like this

```
       EmptyFolderContents_New(recent);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the method with the same name, I don't know how it got there :O. Thanks anyways (:

Comment: I will (: Have to wait 5 minutes though